# how to use serial port throughout my Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, forms, button, serial-port

I'm attempting to make a C# from program that is a simple box with four buttons: left, right, up, and down. then when a button is initially pressed(but not let go) it will send a a serial line. then when the button is unclicked(user lets go of left mouse button) i want to send another serial command.

the issue is that each `void OnClick... (object sender, System.EventArgs e)` is separate from the others and the serial port "port" doesn't work throughout the whole program. i have in main for serial use:

```
SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Open();
```

i didn't want to open and close the serial port each time i want to send something because it may be too close together(in terms of time) and may cause the "serial port in use" issue and or lag in the sending of the serial line.

slimmed down as much as i could.

code:

```
    public class EAS_ControlForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        private Button Up4;
        private Button Down3;
        private Button Left2;
        private Button Right1;
        public EAS_ControlForm()
        {
            Text = "Etch-a-Sketch Control";
            Down3 = new Button ();
            Up4 = new Button ();
            Left2 = new Button ();
            Right1 = new Button ();

            Down3.Text = "Down";
            Down3.Name = "Down3";
            Down3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (72, 30);
            Down3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point ((ClientRectangle.Width - Down3.Size.Width) / 2, ClientRectangle.Height - 10);
            Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] {this.Down3});
            Down3.Click += new System.EventHandler(OnClickDown3);

            Up4.Text = "Up";
            ///...button up4 stuff here like down 3 above.

            Left2.Text = "Left";
            ///...button left2 stuff here like down 3 above.

            Right1.Text = "Right";
            ///...button right1 stuff here like down 3 above.
        }

        static public void Main() 
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Open();

            Application.Run(new EAS_ControlForm());
        }

        void OnClickDown3 (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Write("<3,100>");
        }

        void OnClickUp4 (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Write("<4,100>"); //error here because of port initialization not in same code
        }

        void OnClickLeft2 (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Write("<2,100>"); 
        }

        void OnClickRight1 (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            port.Write("<1,100>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static SerialPort port;
static public void Main()          
{             
    port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    port.Open();              
    Application.Run(new EAS_ControlForm());         
}
```

Comment: i think i got yours to work, but im not sure, as i cant use putty and my app at the same because: 1. if i have putty on first, then my program crashes. 2. if i open my program first then putty, putty wont connect.

Comment: Windows doesn't allow more than one process to open a serial port at the same time. It's possible to make a driver that opens a serial port and then shares it out via two virtual serial ports, but this is a little complicated to do.

Comment: that's what i was thinking. i didn't have access to the robot to be connected to the serial port, so i could actually test it. just trying to see if it was sending commands. ive tried it now with the drawing robot and it does work, so  thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
Try introducing a member function to share the serial port reference or send it through the constructor.

    SerialPort port ;
    public void SetSerialPort(SerialPort p_serialPort )
    {
        port = p_serialPort;
    }

    static public void Main() 
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        EAS_ControlForm myform = new EAS_ControlForm();
        myform.SetSerialPort(port);

        Application.Run(myform);
    }
```

See if this is what you wanted.

Comment: hmm, it compiles ok, but then when i press a button i dont get anything over serial.

Comment: There are a few things you need to check 1. Check if the baudrate, stop bits, parity etc, are correct, 2. Also you can send a command like "AT" to see if your port responds. 3. If you still do not receive anything and data is not received, try using a tool like Putty's serial port option 3. If putty receives, then your program should also receive the data with the same parameter set.

Comment: i tried putty first as soon as i tried your code, and still nothing. the bits, parity etc are right because ive used these settings before.

Comment: Do you mean to say you are not receiving any thing from Putty?

Answer (score 0):

Simply define the `port` as a class member. Initialize it in the form's constructor, or on the `Load` event.