# Accessing Serial Port for multiple forms C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, user-interface

I am working on a Windows app that communicates with a device through a Serial Port. From form one, I connect to the port and send a password to the device. Then, there are 12 options for setting. By clicking on the setting button in Form 1, a second form pops up with 12 options on it. There are 12 buttons on the second form, each sending a message to the device. How can I add a second form to my serial port class?
here is my some part of my serial port class:

```
namespace SerialPort_GUI
{
    class SerialComm : SerialPort
    {
        private Boolean IsReceiving = false;
        private Boolean IsRuning = false;
        private Boolean IsPeriodSending = false;
        private int sleepTime = 200;
        Thread receivingThread = null;

        Form1 form;
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SerialComm"/> class.
        public SerialComm(Form1 form)
        {
            this.form = form;
            base.WriteTimeout = 100;
            //base.= new SerialPort();
            receivingThread = new Thread(DoReceive);
            IsRuning = true;
            receivingThread.Start();
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Did you check the existing very similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44389748/methods-to-use-the-serial-port-in-multiple-forms and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801573/how-to-use-serial-port-throughout-my-windows-forms-application?

Comment: Relay the message / result to Form1; then have Form1 dispatch it. Serial Ports have a "thread affinity". If you start trying to access it from multiple forms, you may get a cross-threading error. (Something to watch for)

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing the message/result back to Form1 by passing an instance of Form1 to the constructor of the SerialComm class and holding a reference to Form1 in the SerialComm class.

In this case, when you create the second form (Form2), you can pass a reference to the SerialComm class so that Form2 can send messages to the device and the SerialComm class can pass the results back to Form1.

```cs
  public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     private SerialComm serialComm;

     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         serialComm = new SerialComm(this);
     }

     public void HandleReceivedData(string data)
     {
         // Handle received data here
     }

     private void OpenForm2Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // Open Form2 and pass reference to SerialComm
         Form2 form2 = new Form2(serialComm);
         form2.Show();
     }
 }
```

Form2:

```cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private SerialComm serialComm;

    public Form2(SerialComm serialComm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.serialComm = serialComm;
    }

    private void SendMessageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        serialComm.SendData("YourMessageHere");
    }
}
```

SerialComm:

```cs
  public class SerialComm : SerialPort
 {
     private Boolean IsReceiving = false;
     private Boolean IsRuning = false;
     private Boolean IsPeriodSending = false;
     private int sleepTime = 200;
  
     private Form1 form;
     private Thread receivingThread;

     public SerialComm(Form1 form)
     {
         this.form = form;
         base.WriteTimeout = 100;
         receivingThread = new Thread(DoReceive);
         receivingThread.Start();
     }

     private void DoReceive()
     {
         while (true)
         {
             if (IsRuning)
             {
                 // Receive data from the device
                 string data = ReadLine();

                 // Pass the received data to Form1
                 form.HandleReceivedData(data);
             }
         }
     }

     public void SendData(string data)
     {
         WriteLine(data);
     }
 }
```